Loss of df when taking inverse of Wishart distribution
Let $\mathbf M$ be a Wishart matrix  from $n$ observations of $p$-variate Normals having dispersion $\mathbf \Sigma$. Then,
$$
 \frac{\mathbf a^{\mathsf T} \mathbf M \mathbf a}{\mathbf a^{\mathsf T} \mathbf \Sigma \mathbf a} \sim \chi^2_n 
$$
yet
$$
 \frac{\mathbf a^{\mathsf T} \mathbf \Sigma^{-1} \mathbf a}{\mathbf a^{\mathsf T} \mathbf M^{-1} \mathbf a} \sim \chi^2_{n - p + 1}  \mathpunct.
$$
Is there any intuition on where this loss in df is coming from? I couldn't track down anything in the proof.

What is $\mathbf{M}$, and what is $\mathbf{a}$ in this context? You may get more engagement if you provide more steps here.

@Cryo Sorry, $\mathbf W$ was a mistake. $\mathbf a$ is any appropriate vector.
